# Waiting image in web page

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a small problem here.

I am working on a web application which is based on jsp and servlets. I am querying some data from a oracle database based on a user search criteria.An Ajax request handle the database query.

Since the amount of data to be fetched is quite large, there is some delay and I want to show an indicator in the jsp page while the data is populated to the page.(like a spinning wheel etc.). Is there a way to do this?

Your help here is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a gif image in your application for showing that, just create a  tag in the html.

and show that **img** when ajax request is sent,
on completion just hide that **img**.

you could use following image as the loader icon.

https://media.tenor.com/images/a6a6686cbddb3e99a5f0b60a829effb3/tenor.gif